# How does element membership work in Perl 6?

Tags: set, raku

Consider this example

```
my @fib =  (1,1, * + * … * > 200).rotor(2 => -1); 
say @fib[0] ∈  @fib; # prints True
```

The first statement creates a [Sequence](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Seq) of 2-element subsequences via the use of the [rotor](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/rotor) function. `@fib` will contain `(1,1)`, `(1,2)` and so on. Quite obviously, the first element of a sequence is part of a sequence. Or is it?

```
my @fib =  (1,1, * + * … * > 200).rotor(2 => -1); 
say @fib[0], @fib[0].^name; # OUTPUT: «(1 1)List␤»
```

So the first element contains a list whose value is (1 1). OK, let's see

```
my $maybe-element = (1,1); 
say $maybe-element, $maybe-element.^name; # OUTPUT: «(1 1)List␤»
say $maybe-element ∈  @fib;               # OUTPUT: «False␤»
```

Wait, what? Let's see...

```
my $maybe-element = @fib[0]; 
say $maybe-element ∈ @fib; # OUTPUT: «True␤»
```

Hum. So it's not the container. But

```
say (1,1).List === (1,1).List; # OUTPUT: «False␤»
```

And

```
say (1,1).List == (1,1).List; # OUTPUT: «True␤»
```

So I guess `∈` is using object identity, and not equality. That being the case, how can we check, in sets or sequences of lists, if an independently generated list is included using this operator? Should we use another different strategy?

Maybe a subquestion is why the same literals generate completely different objects, but there's probably a good, and very likely security-related, answer for that.

Comment: "So I guess ∈ is using object identity, and not equality".  Yes, *all* set operators semantically change whatever given to the necessary `QuantHash` structure.  In the case of `@fib[0] ∈  @fib`, you should consider the right-hand side to have done a `.Set` on it, so equivalent to `@fib[0] ∈  @fib.Set`.  And `Set`s work with object identities.  Some cases may have been optimised for better performance.  In the ``@fib[0] ∈  @fib` case, internally the functional equivalent of `?@fib.first( { .WHICH eq @fib[0].WHICH } )` is done so that it doesn't actually need to process all of the values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So I guess ∈ is using object identity, and not equality.

That is correct.

> That being the case, how can we check, in sets or sequences of lists, if an independently generated list is included using this operator?

You can use `.grep` or `.first` and the equality operator of your choice (presumably you want `eqv` here), or you can try to find a list-like value type. Off the top of my head, I don't know if one is built into Perl 6.

Comment: Sometimes I think we should re-instate `Parcel` as a subclass of `List`.  Coercing to `Parcel` would create a copy of the `$!reified` with all values deconted, and have a value `.WHICH` generated from that.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen +1, but please call it `Tuple` not `Parcel` :D.